# How to blur HDRI image in cycles

Tags: hdri

How to blur HDRI image in cycles. What nodes i have to setup in the world tab to make it blur and control the blur effect.

Comment: I think the answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/112505) will work in your situation. However, in terms of performance, you'd probably be much better off blurring it in an image editor before hand.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms in the substance painter there is a quick option to control the hdri blur. Same way if it is available to control. Thanks

Comment: @cegaton is it possible before render. Blur the HDRI with nodes. without jumping the composition.

Comment: Please **read** the link, you can blur textures by manipulating the coordinates.

Comment: @atek You can blur them with nodes as demonstrated in the links. There is not, however a built in "blurring" feature like in substance painter.