# Is there a resolution to render time ratio?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I was doing some test renders on a project at 5% resolution and I realize it takes much less time than expected to 100% with the same render settings.

100% resolution takes about 7 minutes to render a single frame, while 5% takes little over 6 seconds. And I'm wondering, is there some sort of ratio to calculate render times depending on the resolution of the render?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112505/why-is-my-half-resolution-render-taking-a-quarter-of-the-time-of-the-full-one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is hard to predict. Render time is divided on two pieces: a preparation (resolution independent) and an actual rendering (depends on resolution mostly). Second part, typically in quadratic dependence on size. If you make the image 50% instead of 100%, it will make render time of this part 4 times faster. This is because the render image is 2-dimentional, you decrease the image size in both sides X and Y in the same time, so that 50% of render size means 25% of its area